# How do I set windows to perform auto login?

Tags: windows

Windows has a feature that allows an administrator to perform auto-logon whenever it is started. How can this feature be activated?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Based on the advice, moved the answer to the answers section:

There are tools out there that give you a GUI for setting this easily, but you can also do it relatively easily by editing the registry.

Under the following registry key:
HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\Winlogon

Add the following values:

- DefaultDomainName     String  < domain-name >
- DefaultUserName   String  < username >
- DefaultPassword   String  < password >
- AutoAdminLogon    String  1

Important: Using auto-logon is insecure and should, in general, never be used for standard computer configurations. The problem is not only that your computer is accessible to anyone with physical access to it, but also that the password is saved in plain-text in a well known location in your registry. This is usually used for test environments or for special setups. This is even more important to notice if you intend to perform auto-logon as an administrator.

Comment: The problem of this solution is that it stores the password as clear-text in the registry, which is a security issue.

Answer (score 1):

If you don't want to store the clear-text password in the registry, use this method:

- Start -> Run
- enter "control userpasswords2"
- disable checkbox "Users must enter a user name and password to use this computer"
- click "OK"
- enter a valid user name and password that is used for auto-logon